# How do Square Free Integers link to the PNT?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

It is a fairly well known fact that

$Q(x) = \frac{6}{\pi^2}x + O(\sqrt{x})$

where the function $Q(x)$, denotes the number of square free integers $\le$ x.

There is even a wikipedia page that gives a short proof of this result - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer#Distribution

I've heard in some places that a slightly stronger version of this is equivalent to the prime number theorem (PNT). Say with an error term of $O(x^{\frac{1}{2} - \epsilon})$ or  $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\log{x}}$

Essentially, $Q(x) = \frac{6}{\pi^2}x + o(\sqrt{x})$ implying the PNT.

However, I currently don't know of a proof for this, and would appreciate if anyone knows of one that I could find out about.

Comment: I think, the prime number theorem is a much stronger statement than the statement about the asymptotic frequency of the squarefree numbers. I doubt that we can derive it only from this easy to prove statement.